# which Web Form Event use in ASP.NET web app to avoid return to a page previous

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, page-lifecycle, page-load-time

from a webform file named pointA.aspx where a cookie will be initialized and sent to the webform pointB.aspx that will receive and consume that cookie.

The way the cookie is sent will be through the click event of a button where it will be redirected to the webform pointB.

I need to implement the corresponding logic so that once said cookie is sent to the webform pointB.aspx, it cannot return or access the webform pointA.aspx

I tried to validate the value of the cookie, but without success, this is implemented in the page load by means of an IF (it only works when the page is reloaded by means of an <kbd>F5</kbd>)

```
webform pointA.aspx

       namespace Test
    {
       public partial class pointA : Page
    {       
        HttpCookie hamburger = new HttpCookie("hamburger", "0");
        
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            if (Request.Cookies["hamburger"].value == "5")
            {
                Response.Redirect("pointB.aspx");
            }
        }
        
        protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            hamburger.Value = "5";
            hamburger.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(40);
            Response.Cookies.Add(hamburger);
            Response.Redirect("pointB.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

webform pointB.aspx

```
    namespace Test
     {
       public partial class pointB : Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.Cookies["hamburger"] != null)
            {
               txtLabelHamburger.text = Request.Cookies["hamburger"].value.ToString();
            }
 

        }
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid code sniffed to change your submit form, here is one way to try.

```
1) On Form load pointA.aspx, create unique UUID/GUID hidden input in form 
   using server side and insert the record in a UniqueFormSubmit Table 

2) On form redirect to pointB.aspx, validate if unique UUID/GUID record existed in a 
   UniqueFormSubmit Table and status NOT COMPLETED, then mark it STATUS COMPLETED PROCESSED.  
   If record already exist in the table 
   with STATUS COMPLETED PROCESSED, 
   then reject the re-submit form.
```

Comment: I did not fully understand the answer you gave me, in fact I completely just have a submit form but I appreciate your time invested.